# How to keep specific row at bottom of order?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table `ContactsCategoriesTable` with a column `name`. Names in such column can be anything and 'UNSORTED' in particular. I want to make such an `order by` clause that my query is first sorted by `ContactsCategoriesTable.Name`, then by `ContactsTable.NAME` and `UNSORTED` rows are always at the bottom of table.

I tried this code, but without success. How to write such a clause?

```
sortOrder = ContactsCategoriesTable.NAME + " ASC, " + ContactsTable.NAME + " ASC, "
              + ContactsCategoriesTable.NAME + " = 'UNSORTED' ASC ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A category name being "UNSORTED" is 'stronger' than any other sorting criteria, so you need to sort by that *first*:

```
ORDER BY Category.Name = 'UNSORTED', Category.Name, Contact.Name
```